# python use time.time() as a counter for my program

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, time

I'm trying to use the currentSecond, minute and hour as a counter for an if statement but the result when you print out the currentMinute is sometimes negative, when I change all of the floats to ints I dont get an error and it works fine, is something wrong with my algorithm or is the problem with what I am trying to accomplish??

```
#assume some rate, for example 
rate=2.2

startTime= float(time.time())
currentTime = (float(time.time())-startTime) * float(rate)
currentHour = float(currentTime/3600)
currentMinute = (float(currentTime-currentHour*3600)/60)
currentSecond = float(currentTime-currentHour*3600-currentMinute*60)
```

Comment: Why are you casting time.time() to a float? It should already be a float.

Comment: because I was casting it to an int and I just replaced every instance of int with the word float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you convert back to int just for the currentTime line after doing the math the result will be close to what is desired, but not perfect, this is what I did.

```
#this will be a float
rate=2.2
#this is a float like hirsh said
startTime= (time.time())
currentTime = int(time.time()-startTime) * float(rate))
currentHour = (currentTime/3600)
currentMinute = (currentTime-currentHour*3600)/60
currentSecond = (currentTime-currentHour*3600-currentMinute*60)
```